# How to add content deliver as a related list of opportunity in vf page

Tags: visualforce

Anyone has any idea how to add content deliver as a related list of opportunity in vf page.

Note: *I am not using apex:detail page to display related list.*

[image: Related List Screenshot]

Comment: What do you mean by content deliver?

Comment: I have edit the question. Can u check

Answer (score 1):

I dont think that is possible because in order to show it in related list by using related tag you need to have relationshipName but however with content it looks like it has no relationshipName. 
Please check this snapshot from workbench:
[image]

You can see contract has Contracts as relationship name but not the same case with content. However you can create custom component which takes sobject id as a paremeter and by making queries on ContentDistribution you could get create your own related list component showing content delieries. Hope this helps you.